# Unable to sign into my Samsung Galaxy Tab A

Tags: samsung

I forgot my password and have tried to log back in I never saw anything to reset my password and now every time I try to sign in it states try in 60 minutes. I tried holding down the power and the volume button and I do not see anything to bypass the lock. How can I get back into my Samsung Galaxy Tab A

Answer (score 0):

If you have Android Device Manager installed or Logged in to Samsung account these links may help you [Android device manager and try resetting the password](https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager?u=0) or 
[Samsung find my mobile](https://findmymobile.samsung.com/?p=home) do this both from any other device.